# How to retry all celery tasks when OperationalErrors occur?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, celery

Occasionally when postgres is restarted I get a flood of errors from Celery because of `OperationalError`s. Things like:

```
File "/var/www/.virtualenvs/xxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
OperationalError: terminating connection due to administrator command
SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

Is there a way to just automatically restart any celery tasks that end this way, perhaps with a 30s delay or something? I'm using redis as my broker.

I could catch this kind of error in my task, but it'd mean wrapping every database command in a try/except, which would be kind of horrific.

Comment: Any incomplete tasks should still be in the redis queue. You'll have to define the retrying logic, though, which is a feature that celery provides. See the [retrying](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying) section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Celery [supports retrying](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying) failed tasks. You can configure the delay as a default at the task level and, if needed, on a per-exception basis.

```
@app.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=30)  # retry in 30 seconds.
def add(self, x, y):
    try:
        something_risky()
    except Exception as exc:
        # overrides the default delay to retry after 1 minute
        raise self.retry(exc=exc, countdown=60)
```

If you only wanted retry on `OperationalError` (or other specific errors) you can specify

```
@app.task(autoretry_for=(OperationalError,))
```

There is also builtin support for [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff), via the `retry_backoff` parameter, which will probably be useful for your case.

```
@app.task(autoretry_for=(OperationalError,), retry_backoff=True)
```

Comment: Oh, too bad, only supported in Celery 4.0. I guess I'll get this fixed eventually, because that upgrade looks vicious.

Comment: Yes, `autoretry_for` was added in 4.0 and `retry_backoff` in 4.1 -- the other retrying features look like they're available in 3.x -- Good luck!